# What is the role of $n$ in a finite set (reverse maths)?

Tags: logic, reverse-math

Currently I am reading [Simpson's Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/subsystems-of-second-order-arithmetic/EA16CB4305831530B7015D6BC46B7424), Chapter 2, Recursive Comprehension (RCA$_0$)

The author stated the following theorem at page $67.$

> Theorem $2.5$ The following is provable in RCA$_0$. For any finite set $X\subseteq \mathbb{N},$ there exist $k,m$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
>   $$\forall i(i\in X\leftrightarrow(i<k \wedge m(i+1)+1 \text{ divides }n)).$$

I think $m$ is an upper bound of $X$ and $m$ is the lowest common multiple of all elements of $X.$

However, I am not able to figure out the role of $n.$

The author also mentions that each finite set of natural numbers has a unique code.

Comment: You have to review the *pairing map* (page 66) and line (page 67) : "The least number of the form $(k, (m, n))$ such that (3) holds is called the *code* of the finite set $X$". Thus the three numbers encode in an unique way the number of the finite set $X$ meaning that from $X$ we can compute the code and from the code we can "encode" it to recover all the elements of $X$. And the same for finite *sequences* (page 68).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think there is a meaning to the code of a finite set, right? Yes, I understand that a unique code allows us to recover the set $X$ and vice versa.

Comment: You have to try with some simple example to check how the encoding schema works. Basically, $n$ is the product of the factors $m(i+1)+1$ for the $i \in X$. $(i+1)$ is needed in order to manage the case $0 \in X$.

Comment: $n$ is a possible code for the set $X$.  In computability theory we might call $n$ a "characteristic index" for the set  - it is an index from which we can easily compute the characteristic function of the set.